# What's wrong with my amplified ear circuit?

Tags: transistors, amplifier

Good day! I just want to ask what's wrong with this circuit?
Since the livewire doesn't have a microphone component, i replaced it with an AC source since our goal is to amplify the signal.
It's odd because when I simulate the circuit the output is distorted.

Hope you can help me.

[image: Circuit]
[image: Output Waveform]

Edit:

This is the circuit I used:

[www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/HearingAid-2/HearingAid-2.html](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/HearingAid-2/HearingAid-2.html)

UPDATE:[image: New circuit]
I tried to fix the circuit based on the comments. It seems that the input and the output is not pulsating. From what I know, this is supposed to amplify and not distort the output waveform.

//---------------------------------------------\

UPDATE:
I've added a link for the project file.[ProjectFile](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aq_Gq6lqr2owiDHXtBLprs7JpMlR)

Comment: You need to be a bit more explicit and detailed here. E.g. What specifically do you find "distorted" about the output? What channels are we looking at on the O-scope plot? Is red input or output? Try adding a resistor to simulate the headphone output.

Comment: You are feeding it a 1V signal.  You have a 1.5V battery.  Almost any amount of amplicatication will drive the outputs beyond what the battery can supply.  You are also feeding it an unrealistic signal.  Human voice range is 300 to 3000Hz (old fashioned telephone quality.)  Change your input to 0.01 V and the frequency to 1000 Hz.  See what you get.

Comment: The blue one is the input, and the red one is the output. I'm currently fixing the circuit, I'll just give an update. Thank you guys for your time, really appreciated it :)

Comment: The "scope" in your simulation is connected wrong.  Connect the "-" to the ground, and the "+" to the junction of R10 and Q4.

Comment: Still the same output.

Comment: AC source is floating in the update and will thus have no effect.

Comment: I fixed it and still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Audio equipment is *not* supposed to transport low frequencies like 1 Hz. In fact, you could ruin your speakers/headphones with that. Try 100 Hz or 1 kHz for the AC source, as most caps work as high pass filters.

Q4 is not correctly connected for a class A amplifier. Oscilloscopes have a high impedance (1 Megaohm) typically, the simulated one may well be infinite. A BJT cannot work without current flow.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to stackexchange (I didn't know that pressing enter will automatically send the comment). So you are saying that I should fix my Q4 connection and not use an oscilloscope because of its impedance?

Answer (score 1):

The output stage (Q4) does not appear to have any source of power. So you will not get any significant signal out of it.

Note how Q1 is powered through R2, Q2 is powered through R5, Q3 is powered through R6 and R7.  But there is NO power source for Q4.

In your reference circuit, Q4 is powered THROUGH the two 16 ohm ear-pieces.  If you put a 32 ohm resistor from the top of Q4 up to the voltage rail, then you should expect a proper signal into channel 1 of your oscilloscope.

Note also that the original circuit was designed to operate on 3V while your simulation is supplying only 1.5V  That is likely a losing proposition.

Comment: Steady DC current flow through the headphones, even in the original circuit. May kill headphones rather quickly, you really **don't** want DC current in a speaker or headphone coil.

Comment: Yes some speakers/headphones will be destroyed by a DC current. And DC current will likely increase distortion in most transducers. However, SOME transducers (like hearing aid speakers) are designed to have a DC current through them because it greatly reduces the size and weight of the circuit to eliminate the output DC blocking capacitor which may be as big as the battery.  So the prohibition against DC through transducers is not an absolute principle.

Comment: I'm currently fixing the circuit based on your comment. I'll update you if I experience some changes. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Hi! i've updated the circuit. it doesn't look anymore distorted but it's not pulsating like a sinusoidal wave.